# How do I determine when a DIV element, containing an ActiveX control, changes size (without polling)?

Tags: html, activex

I have a DIV that contains an activex control.

This control can resize itself depending on what buttons the user pokes.

When the control resizes itself, I would like to reposition the DIV.

How can I determine when the control or DIV size has changed without polling?

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an [onresize event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536959(VS.85).aspx) on the DIV.

Comment: Within the document you referenced: "This event does not fire for files with embedded controls."

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. But it also says that you can put an onresize handler on the OBJECT or EMBED elements. Note that the wording is that it doesn't apply to "files" with controls -- it may be that it's disabled for local disk files, for security reasons.